# Is it possible to create a non-boxable struct in C#

Tags: c#, clr, boxing, chakra

Copies of some data doesn't belong on the heap (without special treatment.)   For example, the [**JavaScriptValue**](https://github.com/panopticoncentral/chakra-host/blob/master/src/cs/Hosting/JavaScriptValue.cs) struct on the stack, does a great job in interop with the Chakra JavaScript engine.

But as I understand it, storing such a value on the managed heap, (without proper reference counting) results in a possible dangling reference.  Is there a way to declare a c# structure like this as *non-boxable*?

**Clarification**, I want the c# compiler to generate an error message if any boxing operations are generated on the type.

Reference:  See [MSDN JSAddRef reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249659(v=vs.94).aspx) which says:

> This only needs to be called on JsRef handles that are ***not going to be stored 
>   somewhere on the stack.*** Calling JsAddRef ensures that the object the JsRef refers >
>   to will not be freed until JsRelease is called.

I gather from this that Chakra may be using a "conservative garbage collection" approach, *making JsAddRef/JsRelease unnecessary for stack based JsRef handles.*  I would want to use to use a class (not structure) to wrap JsRef handles on the heap, and have a conversion operation to call JsAddRef, and use the IDisposable pattern to call JsRelease.

Comment: It can just as easily dangle as a local variable.  Proper reference counting is required in *all* usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CLI ECMA-335 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) says (section I.8.2.4):

> All value types have an operation called `box`. Boxing a value of any value type produces its boxed value; i.e., a value of the corresponding boxed type containing a bitwise copy of the 
>   original value.

There is some additional language saying what happens with `Nullable<T>` (the contained value is boxed or a null reference is produced) and that the box operation cannot be performed on managed pointers, but there is no mention of any exception for value types.

Comment: Someone down voted this answer without commenting why.   Basically I believe the answer to my original question is No, it can't be done, and this answer provides authoritative reason why so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

With C# 7.2+, the answer is yes: just use the *ref* keyword on your struct `ref struct`. It will be allowed only on the stack, not on the heap (and hence no boxing can be done on it).

See here for more information: http://www.devsanon.com/c/c-7-2-introducing-ref-struct/

And here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code#use-ref-struct-types

Answer (score 0):

it gets boxed because you store it in a datastructure that goes on the heap.

*you* put it there by wrapping it in a non value type.

There are lots of questions around this subject. If you dont want to read a book then you should read all of these. Some of them are v interesting.

So no its not possible to create a non boxable struct - it gets boxed because of what you do.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "wrapping"? I understand that any value type composed by a reference type will be stored on the heap but does a boxing operation occur in such scenarios?

Comment: Thank John, you are probably right, but it sort of misses the point.  I want to declare a struct that will generate an error if boxed.   I'll clarify my question above.

Comment: ok, i don't know. But i don't think you have that much control. I'd assume no but that's more of an I don't know than an absolute no. But given effectively the source code for .net is available you can do anything you like now. The problem is that you cannot override the box method - you dont have direct access to it anyway. You are basically trying to define the definition of the language - and how it manages memory

Comment: @Burt_Harris  https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-heapview  this resharper extension will get you a long way to what you want

Answer (score 0):

As other's have written, value types will be boxed (you can think of it like they're being wrapped in a reference type) to be able to go on the heap.

But more important, this has nothing to do with dangling references and reference counting. Doesn't matter where it's stored.

What I believe you're asking is how to manage native resources, and that's another matter. If you allocate a resource from something outside the .NET world, you generally need to make sure you release/free it when you're done with it. Normally you wrap it up in a class that implements `IDisposable` and dispose of it manually (or in a destructor). Now, if you forget to dispose something you should, or keep a reference to something already disposed, you can get into trouble. But all this depends on what the resource is.

For your specific case with `JavaScriptValue`, I don't really know how that works. Though it looks to me that if the IntPtr in there referred to something that needs to be disposed, `JavaScriptValue` would have been a class implementing IDisposable and not a struct. Storing something that needs to be disposed in a struct would be a very good way of getting into trouble, since you could potentially have copies of that reference all over the place. So I would *assume* that you don't need to bother - but you should check the docs to be sure.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this seems like the best answer so far, but I disagree, this has everything to do with dangling references and reference counting.   I've added some clarifications to the question question.   When stored on the stack, the native *JsRef* handle needs no additional AddRef, but if stored on the heap, then it does (making IDisposable applicable to a heap based instance only.)

Comment: Well yeah true, if the designers make the odd choice of using structs for something like that, I agree completely.